# In the vscode command palette, why is the `dotnet` command not appearing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow along with a tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet), and it asks me to use the Command Palette to do things like `dotnet run` and `dotnet restore`, by typing `dotnet: Restore Packages` into the Command Palette.

I have tried installing the C# extension, and restarting the program several times.  Everything else seems to be working normally, but not the Command Palette.

I've found a work around, which is to just use the terminal, but I'd like to gain a better understanding of why I can't seem to get the same functionality as described in the tutorial.